# Class Object exposed inside Angular

Tags: c#, angularjs, controller

is there a way to expose my Class object inside angular controller? what I mean is that instead of passing a long list of properties to json when submitting like this:

On my class controller I have an object called Person which has about 20 properties.

```
 var fname=$('#fname');
 var lname = $('#lname');
$http.post( '/Review/InsertToPersonObj',
            {
                firstname: fname
                , lastname: lname
               .... and about 15 more 

            })
        .success(function (dResult, status, headers, config) {
            Dialog.Show('Success', 'Comment added successfully.');

            //Refresh

            $scope.GetWeekDetails();

        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

            Dialog.Show('Warning', 'it did not save')


        });
```

I can just have this: Person.FirstName= $('#fname').val();
the purpose is to reduce the amount of text passed under json param, also to make it more readable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this, using string array in javascript, then pass it using JSON.Stringify(object), once it's passed, I parse it on the C# method like so:

```
obj = ({val1, val2, val3});
$http.post('path/method') {( data: JSON.stringify(obj) )};
```